# Using the same parameter 2 (or more) times on a SQL TableAdapter but passing only 1

Tags: vb.net, parameters, tableadapter

I'm facing an issue with VB.NET and the creation of a SQL TableAdapter (using IBM DB2) on a DataSet.

I can use an SQL like this without any issue:

```
select f1, f2, f3 from table where y1=@param1 and y2=@param2
```

And then calling the TableAdapter fill like this:

```
TableAdapter.FillBy(Me.DataSetName.Table, value1, value2)
```

However if I try to do an UNION sentence like:

```
select f1, f2, f3 from table where y1=@param1 and y2=@param2
UNION select f1, f2, f3 from table2 where y1=@param1 and y2=@param2
```

The TableAdapter designer doesn't prompt any error byt when I call the TableAdapter.Fill it asks for 4 parameters instead of 2, like it isn't able to reuse the same parameter even that the name is the same in both SQL tables.

Is there any way to avoid using 4 different parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used DB2 but nobody else seems to have an answer so I'll give it a shot based on my MSSQL experience.

Try augmenting the query with variables so you only need to write them once. (Data Types guessed...):

```
DECLARE v_param1, v_param2 VARCHAR;
SELECT @param1, @param2 INTO v_param1, v_param2;
SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM table WHERE y1=v_param1 AND y2=v_param2
UNION 
SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM table2 WHERE y1=v_param1 AND y2=v_param2
```

Comment: I'm not able to declare variables within the SQL assistant of the TableAdapter. Maybe we are talking about different things ? I'm attaching an image to ilustrate it:
https://s14.postimg.org/9yn906qn5/screenshot.png

Comment: The image is not coming through, but if I recall don't you have a few options regarding how to write your sql like with straight SQL statements, stored procedures, etc?

Comment: It only allows me to run SQL statements or call existent stored procedures. The option to create a new stored procedure at design time is disabled for my DB2 connection (I don't know if it's a limitation of the IBM.Data.DB2 connector).
Maybe it's an IDE limitation (I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010), maybe I should try a trial version of VB2017 to see if that still happends.